# Store jQuery .load() to a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to store the value from the .load (#p3) to a variable. #p3 is loaded from a php script with value 0 or 1.
My example does not work, someone who knows how to do this?

```
    setInterval(
        function(){
            $('#temp_mash').load('update.php #p1');
            $('#reg_mash').load('update.php #p2');
            var v = ($('#farge').load('update.php #p3'));
        }, 1000);
```

Comment: Why store in javascript when the value can be reliably read back from the DOM?

Comment: Don't use `load` for that; `load` is a jQuery shortcut for the specific situation of loading the returned content into a DOM element. For direct access to the values returned by Ajax, use jQuery's `ajax` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `html` function

```
setInterval(
function()
{
    $('#temp_mash').load('update.php #p1');
    $('#reg_mash').load('update.php #p2');
    var v = ($('#farge').load('update.php #p3'));
    var dataYouWant = $("#farge").html();
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.get('update.php #p3', function(data) {
    // do something ...
});
```

or

```
$.post('update.php #p3', function(data) {
    // do something ...
});
```

or

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'update.php #p3',
    success: function(data) {
        // do something ...
    }
});
```